# Why is my grep + regex not working?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, quoting

I recently decided that enough was enough -- I was going to learn to use grep fluently.  It's been all of three hours and I'm already stumped by this toy problem.

I'm currently syncing a RAID5 array, the progress of which can be monitored by reading `/proc/mdstat`.  The output of `cat /proc/mdstat` is shown below.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid5 sda4[0] sdb4[1] sdc4[2]
      5858765824 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      [=============>.......]  resync = 67.3% (1972073120/2929382912) finish=205.7min speed=77537K/sec

md0 : active raid5 sda3[0] sdb3[1] sdc3[2]
      998400 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

For fun, I thought I would use `watch` to monitor `/proc/mdstat` in real time, pipe it's output into grep, and show only the estimated remaining time.

My approach is as follows:

`watch cat /proc/mdstat | grep finish=\d+\.\d | grep \d+\.\d`

I'm stumped as to why this produced no output.  In fact, the first grep expression produces no output, even though it seems to work on [Regex101](http://regex101.com).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `watch 'grep -oP "finish=\K[\d.]+" /proc/mdstat'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
watch cat /proc/mdstat | grep -oE 'finish=[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]' | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]'
```

If you really like the perl-style "\d" format and your grep supports perl-style regexes, then:

```
cat mdstat | grep -oP 'finish=\d+\.\d' | grep -oP '\d+\.\d'
```

where the "-P" option specifies perl-style regular expressions.

The "-o" option tells grep to display only the part of the line that matches the regular expression.  This is what removes the unwanted text and allows us to return only the time remaining.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  I read about the `-P` flag in the meantime, but I wasn't aware of `-o` -- that's a good trick to keep in mind!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
watch cat mdstatout | grep -oP 'finish\=\d+\.\d+' | cut -d= -f2
```

205.7

The `-o` tells grep to only output the matching text and not the whole line and `-P` lets you use perl regex which enables `\d`.

Also, I use `cut` to pull the digits out rather than another regex.